# How to create a frequency matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, count, frequency, nested-lists

I just started using Python and I just came across the following problem:

Imagine I have the following list of lists:

```
list = [["Word1","Word2","Word2","Word4566"],["Word2", "Word3", "Word4"], ...]
```

The result (matrix) i want to get should look like this:
[image: screenshot]

The Displayed Columns and Rows are all appearing words (no matter which list).
The thing that I want is a programm that counts the appearence of words in each list (by list).

The picture is the result after the first list.

Is there an easy way to achieve something like this or something similar?

EDIT:
Basically I want a List/Matrix that tells me how many times words 2-4566 appeared when word 1 was also in the list, and so on.

So I would get a list for each word that displays the absolute frequency of all other 4555 words in relationship with this word.

So I would need an algorithm that iterates through all this lists of words and builts the result lists

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking about. What do  the intersections of columns and rows mean?

Comment: The interesections of columns and rows are not important. I don´t need them, so they could be 0 or blanks or whatsoever

Comment: Could you just clarify what do you want to do? Do you want to count how many times each word appears in each of the lists? If yes what is the connections between number of words and that matrix?

Comment: See the edit. Hope it gets clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with the right answer to my own question:

```
list = [["Word1","Word2","Word2"],["Word2", "Word3", "Word4"],["Word2","Word3"]]

#Names of all dicts
all_words = sorted(set([w for sublist in list for w in sublist]))

#Creating the dicts
dicts = []
for i in all_words:
    dicts.append([i, dict.fromkeys([w for w in all_words if w != i],0)])

#Updating the dicts
for l in list:
    for word in sorted(set(l)):
        tmpL = [w for w in l if w != word]
        ind = ([w[0] for w in dicts].index(word))

        for w in dicts[ind][1]:
            dicts[ind][1][w] += l.count(w)

print dicts
```

Gets the result:

['Word1', {'Word4': 0, 'Word3': 0, 'Word2': 2}], ['Word2', {'Word4': 1,    'Word1': 1, 'Word3': 2}], ['Word3', {'Word4': 1, 'Word1': 0, 'Word2': 2}], ['Word4', {'Word1': 0, 'Word3': 1, 'Word2': 1}]]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to create a matrix that shows the number of lists where two words are located together for each pair of words.

First of all we should fix the set of unique words:

```
lst = [["Word1","Word2","Word2","Word4566"],["Word2", "Word3", "Word4"], ...] # list is a reserved word in python, don't use it as a name of variables

words = set()
for sublst in lst:
    words |= set(sublst)
words = list(words)
```

Second we should define a matrix with zeros:

```
result = [[0] * len(words)] * len(words) # zeros matrix N x N
```

And finally we fill the matrix going through the given list:

```
for sublst in lst:
    sublst = list(set(sublst)) # selecting unique words only
    for i in xrange(len(sublst)):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, len(sublst)):
            index1 = words.index(sublst[i])
            index2 = words.index(sublst[j])
            result[index1][index2] += 1
            result[index2][index1] += 1

print result
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it really hard to understand what you're really asking for, but I'll try by making some assumptions:

- (1) You have a list (*A*), containing other lists (*b*) of multiple words (*w*).
- (2) For each *b*-list in *A*-list

  - (3) For each *w* in *b*:

    - (3.1) count the total number of appearances of *w* in all of the *b*-lists
    - (3.2) count how many of the *b*-lists, in which *w* appears only once

If these assumptions are correct, then the table doesn't correspond correctly to the list you've provided. If my assumptions are wrong, then I still believe my solution may give you inspiration or some ideas on how to solve it correctly. Finally, I do not claim my solution to be optimal with respect to speed or similar.

OBS!! I use python's built-in dictionaries, which may become terribly slow if you intend to fill them with thousands of words!! Have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
    frq_dict = {} # num of appearances / frequency
    uqe_dict = {} # unique

    for list_b in list_A:
            temp_dict = {}
            for word in list_b:
                    if( word in temp_dict ):
                            temp_dict[word]+=1
                    else:
                            temp_dict[word]=1

            # frq is the number of appearances 
            for word, frq in temp_dict.iteritems(): 
                    if( frq > 1 ):
                            if( word in frq_dict )
                                    frq_dict[word] += frq
                            else
                                    frq_dict[word] = frq
                    else:
                            if( word in uqe_dict )
                                    uqe_dict[word] += 1
                            else
                                    uqe_dict[word] = 1
```

Comment: @mgruber I saw your edit to your question a little too late. I'll try to make an updated solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The thing I need is a dictionary for each word, that contains all the other words except the one. the dictionary is then filled by going list by list. So if list 1 contains word1, word1´s dictionary is filled with the number of times word2, word3 and so on is appearing in that same list (only). This is done for each word in the first list. Than move on to list2 if word 1 appears again, the number of times word2, word3 and so on is appearing is added on top of the already existing numbers.

Comment: Indeed. You can solve this by filling a dictionary with other dictionaries. However, this will be terribly slow for many words. You ask for a rather huge amount of information here. Have you figured out how you want to do it then, or do you need more help?